# TypeORM - Order By in raw sql dont work with parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am using `entityManager` and raw query to get data from Postgres database. I have simple query for select and order by `item_id`.
If I write full query as:

`let query = "Select * From item
...
Order By item_id";`
and pass it to entityManager 
`await this.entityManager.query(query)` order by is working correctly.

But if I write query with parameter:

`let query = "Select * From item
...
Order By $1";`
and pass columnName for ordering to entityManager `await this.entityManager.query(query,["item_id"])` order by is completely ignored.

I also tried put columName to property and pass that property to entityManager:
`let columnName = "item_id";
await this.entityManager.query(query,[columnName])`
but with same result.

We have PostgreSql as database and typeorm version ^0.2.9

Does anyone know, where could be the problem? Or is there any workarround to use Order By with parametr in raw sql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the output of the logs from postgresql? We use the `query` method with prepared statements and it works fine.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see from log?

Comment: the raw SQL that postgres received including the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statements are not supported in `ORDER BY` clauses within postgresql. This is because the parameters are values not identifiers.

As a work around you could just use string interpolation in typescript, but the safest way looks like wrapping the SQL statement in a function and using [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) in combination with prepared statements as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKFQuwYR5i0n=kMjkKvDTKwnWyw2F-BgO5EmOjHVpPxOuCm8PQ@mail.gmail.com).